Roots of polynomial in field with characteristic 2
I was reading trough a paper of Keith Conrad an stumbled upon the example $\mathbb{F}_{2}(u)$ where u is transendental and he said the discriminant of $f(x):=x^{3}+ux+u$ is equal to $u^{2}$. I cannot prove this though. I thought if $\alpha$ a root of $f$ then something like $\alpha+\sqrt{u}$ or so would also be a root but that does not seem the case. Can anybody help me with finding the roots? Thanks in advance!

What happens when you use the formula for the discriminant of a cubic?  Keep in mind that the coefficients should be taken $\mod 2$.

yes indeed then you immediately get that the discriminant is $u^{2}$. But still how can I then prove that the degree of the splitting field of $f$ is 6? Having the roots would showing that a lot easier aswell.

With a characteristic two tweak to solving a quadratic, Cardano's method for solving a cubic yields the following. I dare not say whether the formulas below work for you at all :-(, this is just too long to fit into a comment.
The formulas describe the roots of your cubic as elements of the the ring of formal power series $\Bbb{F}_4[[u]](u^{1/3})$ (need to adjoin a cube root $u^{1/3}$ in there) — an integral domain whose field of fractions obviously contains a copy of $\Bbb{F}_2(u)$.

Consider the power series
$$
A=u^2(1+u+u^3+u^7+u^{15}+\cdots)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^{2^j+1}.
$$
The power series $W=u+u^2+u^4+u^8+u^{16}+\cdots$ satisfies the quadratic $W^2+W=u$.
Consequently $A=uW$ satisfies the quadratic
$$
A^2+uA=u^3. \qquad(*)
$$
By Vieta relations the other root of $(*)$ is then $B=u+A$. We also note that $AB=u^3$.
The power series $C^3=1+u+u^3+u^7+u^{15}+\cdots$ has a cube root
$$
C=1+u+u^2+u^6+u^7+\cdots\in\Bbb{F}_2[[u]].
$$
Don't ask me for a formula for the coefficients of $C$ :-). I got those few by Hensel lifting one term at a time (the usual method for producing roots in $\Bbb{F}_2[[u]]$)!
We thus have
$$
A^{1/3}=u^{2/3}C\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=u^{1/3}/C
$$
and they were tailored to satisfy the relevant Cardano system of equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
A^{1/3}B^{1/3}&=&u,\\
A+B&=&u.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Let $\omega\in\Bbb{F}_4$ be a primitive third root of unity. By Cardano, the roots
of your cubic are
$$
x_1=A^{1/3}+B^{1/3},\quad
x_2=\omega A^{1/3}+\omega^2B^{1/3},\quad
x_3=\omega^2 A^{1/3}+\omega B^{1/3}.
$$

This is a bit of a joke answer. I doubt this is useful :-)
